# [ADF]How to adjust Input box width with column width

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using click to edit functionality in af:table, as soon it changes into input text box, text goes out of column.I want input text box to stretch and contract with column width.

Comment: You may set nowrap property of column to false. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try **contentStyle** Property

```
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.Name.inputValue}"
               id="it1" contentStyle="width:10em;"
               autoSubmit="true">
        <f:validator binding="#{bindings.Name.validator}"/>
 </af:inputText>
```